# How to multiply screen resolution by 80% then use in code

Tags: javascript, screen-resolution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Some javascript code here * 80%
</script>

<div style="height:80% of user's availHeight here">
My content
</div>
```

I know it's brief, but hope it explains what I'm looking for.  Much help is greatly appreciated.  Thank You! :)

Comment: If it is just about the dimensions: [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to point out that `screen` resolution has (*almost*) nothing to do with a browser window available height / width.

If you're good with CSS3 you can use [`vh` unit](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

```
<div style="height: 80vh;"> I'm 80% of user's availHeight here </div>
```

Now let's answer literally your question:

> How to multiply screen resolution by 80% then use in code

```
var screenW = screen.width;  // Number of px of Physical screen width 
var screenH = screen.height; // Number of px of Physical screen height
```

You have your screen size values now, multiply and do whatever you need to.

Comment: I sincerely hope that [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) isn't a concern

Comment: @jdphenix I hope that too. Otherwise `html, body{height:100%;} body > div{height:80%;}` will do the same job.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I know. Just thought because the question is a bit inaccurate, the answer might be misleading for people not used the difference of `vh` and `screenHeight`.

Comment: @t.niese yes, thanks. I made a clear statement thanks to your comments at the top of my A.

Comment: Thanks Roko.  It appears 80vh was a valid solution.

Comment: I've always had problems applying 80% to height and I think it has to do with other top level elements.  If html, body, etc isn't 100%, then `height:80%` won't work.